# Removing OSX without deleting media files

Tags: macos, hard-drive

I have two drives on my Mac, Macintosh HDD (Mountain Lion) and Macintosh SSD (Mavericks). I recently installed Mavericks on Macintosh SSD.

I still have Mountain Lion installed on Macintosh HDD along with media files.

What would be a good way to remove Mountain Lion, keeping the media files on that drive.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a spare USB hard drive (or Dropbox/Google Drive/Box.com/iCloud account big enough to hold all your media), I'd just move your media files to that temporarily.

Boot into OS X Mavericks, open Disk Utility, select "Macintosh HDD" from the sidebar, then click the "Erase" tab.  Reformat it to "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)", rename it whatever you like, then put all your media files back on it.